# Breaking the file connection in Mercurial after bad file split

Tags: mercurial

**Background:**

At first there was a file `base.c`, and that file was in the repository which had only one branch `Base`.

`Base` was branched to make `Extended`-branch. Then this new branch had several changes made to `base.c`.

If bugs were fixed in file `base.c` in `Base`, they would be merged to `Extended`.

It turns out that adding too much stuff to `base.c` in `Extended` branch was not a good idea, so file is copied to `ext.c`. Then most of the `Extended` additions are removed from `base.c`, and `Base` functionality from `ext.c`. So at this point `base.c` in `Extended` is very similar as in `Base`.

**Problem:**

When file was split, Mercurial was informed that `ext.c` is a copy of `base.c`, because they shared a common history. Unfortunately this was not a good idea.

Now if bugs are fixed on `Base` branch and merged to `Extended`, Mercurial thinks that those changes should be applied to both `base.c` and `ext.c`, even though the latter is no longer has any similarities to former. This makes the merges very annoying.

Is there a way to tell the Mercurial that `ext.c` should no longer be considered same as `base.c`? One solution would be to replace `ext.c` with new file, but then history would not follow.

Comment: Interesting problem. I assume you made the copy with `hg copy`?

Comment: Yes `hg copy` was used.

Comment: You could break the connection if you `hg forget ext.c` and then `hg add` it as a new file... but then you'd lose all history up to this point. However, you could add an _earlier_ version of `ext.c` (maybe even before the rename), and replay (graft) it's history since then.

Comment: @alexis That is what I eventually ended up doing. You should probably add that as an answer as this question seems to get some activity occasionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break the connection with `hg forget ext.c`, and then `hg add ext.c` as a new file. But if you do this with the tip revision of `ext.c`, you'll lose all history up to this point.

What you can do instead is to add an earlier version of `ext.c`, maybe even from before the rename, and replay (graft) its history since then. You could add the history of `ext.c` as a branch to a past revision, and merge it into tip:

```
---o---o---o---(tip)--(merge)
    \                /
     e---e---e ...  e
```

Or perhaps it doesn't matter, and you can just add the history of `ext.c` to the current `tip`:

```
---o---o---o---(tip)--e--e--e--e
```

Neither of these approaches involves any history rewriting (the "forgotten" version of `ext.c` is just left as a dead end), so there should be no problems with propagating changes.